# How to run CQL in Zeppelin by taking input in user input format?

Tags: cassandra, interpreter, cql, apache-zeppelin, cqlsh

I was trying to run CQL query by taking in user input format in Zeppelin tool:-

```
%cassandra

SELECT  ${Select Fields Type=uuid ,uuid | created_by |  email_verify| username} FROM 
${Select Table=keyspace.table_name} 
${WHERE email_verify="true" } ${ORDER BY='updated_date' }LIMIT ${limit = 10};
```

while running this query I was getting this error:

```
line 4:0 mismatched input 'true' expecting EOF 
   (SELECT uuid FROM keyspace.table_name ["true"]...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` out of the dynamic form declaration.

The input field declaration is looks as [following](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/dynamic_form/intro.html#text-input-form): `${field_name=default_value}`. In your case, instead of `WHERE ...`, you've got the field name of `WHERE email_verify`.

It should be as following (didn't tested):

```
%cassandra

SELECT ${Select Fields Type=uuid ,uuid | created_by |  email_verify| username} FROM 
${Select Table=keyspace.table_name} 
WHERE ${where_cond=email_verify='true'} ORDER BY ${order_by='updated_date'} LIMIT ${limit = 10};
```

Update:

here is the working example for table with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test.scala_test2 (
    id int,
    c int,
    t text,
    tm timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, c)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (c ASC)
```

[image: working example]

Comment: It didn't worked as it shows the error as:- no viable alternative at input 'ORDER'

Comment: Check the syntax for WHERE condition - you're using the double quotes for value, but it's not the CQL syntax. I've updated the answer with working example...